# Sum of $\sum\frac{1}{i^{i}}$

Tags: calculus, summation

Few minutes ago I saw the sum: $$\sum(i^{i})$$, and there is no normal equation to describe that.

My question is:
Find the $$\sum\frac{1}{i^{i}}$$ , if it's exist of course.

Comment: What is the range of $i$ for that sum?

Comment: Edit: OP is interested in $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-k}$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 no, I interested in infinity sum..sry for my english

Comment: Well it definitely converges.  Not sure you can figure out what it converges to tho.

Comment: This is the sum that appears in the [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream). It is approximately 1.2913, but I'm not sure if anyone knows a closed form.

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli thanks a lot for information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the known question of mathematical competitions: I try to prove it with details

We know $x^{-x}=e^{-x\ln x}$, so we have $$x^{-x}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n\ln^nx}{n!} $$ which for $0<x\leq 1$ is uniform convergence (since the maximum $|x\ln x|$ in [0,1] is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$) so we have the following upper bound for it , $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\frac{1}{e})^n}{n!}$, so we can take integral of each summand. But we know $\int_0^1x^n\ln^nxdx=(-1)^n\frac{n!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$ hence $$\int_0^1x^{-x}dx=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{m^m}$$